# How can I fix the bug where Apache Superset menu titles disappear upon login

Tags: apache-superset

I am currently running Apache Superset using the docker-compose-non-dev.yml file from the Superset GitHub repository. As of September 3, 2022, this was the latest version available.

However, I am encountering a bug where the menu titles in Apache Superset disappear upon logging in. Strangely, if I click on settings or refresh the page, the menu titles reappear. This issue is causing inconvenience and inconsistency in the application's navigation.

To provide further context and aid in troubleshooting, I have attached a screenshot capturing the specific issue. The screenshot shows the Apache Superset interface immediately after logging in, where the menu titles are missing.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYnOi.jpg)

I have already attempted to resolve the problem by restarting the server and clearing the browser cache, but unfortunately, the issue persists.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to fix this bug and ensure that the menu titles remain consistently visible upon login.

Thank you for your assistance.